# Send excel sheet content in mail body using jenkins

Tags: excel, email, jenkins

In Jenkins, Under Editable Email Notification I have set the Default Content fields as

`${FILE,path="\\ProjectFolder\\Reports\\HTMLReport.html"}
with Content Type = Default Content Type`

And I am getting the html content in my email body.
But when I am trying to set email body content from excel using

`${FILE,path="\\ProjectFolder\\Reports\\ReportSummary.xlsx"}
with Content Type = Default Content Type`

I am not getting any email from jenkins.

Someone please help.

Comment: Did you try to add it as an attachment instead?

Comment: Adding attachment is success. 
And I noticed that the email is getting triggered but going to junk email folder as the body of content(which is excel content written in plain text) is a junk value like 
`æÞÍ¶‚ˆ4íE„ÞDê ŒÉìnØÝLH¦uûö /jí‚‚Çd2ßÿ‘™õv u¤”=`

Is there a way to specify excel format in jenkins?

Comment: Nope, what you can do is send a regular html body with a regular message, with the excel file as attachment.

Comment: Nope I want to send excel sheet content as email content, not as an attachment.

Comment: Good luck @ram :)

Comment: Got you @Hackerman. Can't send excel content as email body. So converting excel to HTML and publishing it through jenkins. Thanks for the idea.